# Django daphne service service is not working while deploying on aws ec2 an error Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, daphne

Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 python[92893]:   File "/home/ubuntu/nextshelters/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 72, in _setup
Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 python[92893]:     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 python[92893]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJ>
Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 systemd[1]: daphne.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 systemd[1]: daphne.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 systemd[1]: daphne.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 06 11:11:00 ip-172-31-12-99 systemd[1]: Stopped WebSocket Daphne Service.

this is the error coming when i am trying to do this sudo journalctl -u daphne.service
here is m asgi.py file

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Renter.settings')
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter, get_default_application
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path
from home.consumers import ChatConsumer, NotificationsConsumer, TenantsConsumer


application = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    path("chat/<room_code>", ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                    path("view_messages", NotificationsConsumer.as_asgi()),
                    path("dashboard/tenant_details/<tenant_uid>", TenantsConsumer.as_asgi())
                ]
            )
        ),
    }
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.